# What is Activity.setDefaultKeyMode?

Tags: android

I am looking into API document about Activity. I see a method 'setDefaultKeyMode', but I can't understand clearly what it is for. Would anybody please explain about which all key is affected and how does the default behaviour differ from other options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't that much to understand--it's to determine how key events that aren't handled in any other way (like by `onKeyDown`) are handled. By default, they just "go away". (Not system keys, app keys.)

The [method's Javadocs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setDefaultKeyMode%28int%29) describe the other modes.